# How do I enable/disable checkboxes when another checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I got on how to check/unchecked or hide/show when one checkbox is checked but what im looking for is when I have 5 checkboxes Fastfood, Catering, Carryout, Delivery and Bar when user clicked Fastfood ,rest checkboxes are disable, when user checked Catering, rest are disable but when user checked Carryout only Fastfood and Catering are disable. Then when user unchecked, all checkboxes back to enable/show. thanks! –

Here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function HideOrShowStuff(controlToHide1)
{


       if (document.getElementById)
   {
          if(controlToHide1==1)
      {
      document.getElementById('2').disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('3').disabled = true;
          document.getElementById('4').disabled = true;
           document.getElementById('5').disabled = true;
           document.getElementById('1').disabled = false;
             }
        if(controlToHide1==2)
      { 
         document.getElementById('1').disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('2').disabled = false;
          document.getElementById('4').disabled = true;
           document.getElementById('5').disabled = true;
           document.getElementById('3').disabled = true;
              }
                  if(controlToHide1==3)
      { 
          document.getElementById('1').disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('2').disabled = true;
          document.getElementById('4').disabled = false;
           document.getElementById('5').disabled = false;
           document.getElementById('3').disabled = false;
              }
                  }
        }

</script>

 Type of restaurant are you?<br /> <br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="restaupop1"  id="1"value="fastfood" onclick="HideOrShowStuff(1)"    <?PHP print $fastfood_status; ?>> Fast Food/Drive Thru  <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="restaupop2" id="2"value="catering"  onclick="HideOrShowStuff(2); setVisible('restaubar');"   <?PHP print $catering_status; ?>> Catering<br />
<input type="checkbox"  name="restaupop3" id="3" value="carryout"  onclick="HideOrShowStuff(3)"   <?PHP print $carryout_status; ?>> Carry-Out<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="restaupop4" id="4"value="delivery"   onclick="setVisible('barpop1');"  <?PHP print $delivery_status; ?>> Delivery<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="restaupop5" id="5"value="bargrill" onclick="setVisible('restaubar');"     <?PHP print $bargrill_status; ?>>Bar/Grill
```

Comment: You have PHP code in there too, what is the HTML version of this? I can't tell until the document is rendered.

Comment: the html version is very long... but to make it sure..this is what im looking for.....i got on how to check/unchecked or hide/show when one checkbox is checked but let see when I have 5 checkboxes Fastfood, Catering, Carryout, Delivery and Bar when user clicked Fastfood ,rest checkboxes are disable, when user checked Catering, rest are disable but when user checked Carryout only Fastfood and Catering are disable. Then when user unchecked, all checkboxes back to enable/show. thanks! –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All in all, not too difficult.

http://jsfiddle.net/A5TGf/19/

HTML:

```
<form action="./" id="checkForm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="foo">foo</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="foo" value="foo" />
        <label for="bar">bar</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="bar" value="bar" />
        <label for="baz">baz</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="baz" value="baz" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var form = document.getElementById("checkForm");
form.onclick = delegateFormClick;

addChangeHandlers(form);

function addChangeHandlers(form)
{
   for(var i=0;i<form.elements.length;i++)
   {
       var element = form.elements[i];
       if(element.tagName === "INPUT" && element.type === "checkbox")
       {
           if(!element.onchange)
           {
               element.onchange = checkBoxChanged;   
           }
       }
   }  
}

function delegateFormClick(evt)
{
    var target;
    if(!evt)
    {
        //Microsoft DOM
        target = window.event.srcElement;
    }else if(evt)
    {
        //w3c DOM
        target = evt.target;
    }
    if(target.nodeType === 1 && target.tagName === "INPUT" && target.type === "checkbox")
    {
        if(target.checked)
        {
            disableCheckBoxes(target.id, document.getElementById("checkForm"));
        }else if(!target.checked)
        {
            enableCheckBoxes(document.getElementById("checkForm"));
        }  
    }
}

function checkBoxChanged()
{
    if(this.checked)
    {
       disableCheckBoxes(this.id, document.getElementById("checkForm"));
    }else if(!this.checked)
    {
        enableCheckBoxes(document.getElementById("checkForm"));  
    }
}

function disableCheckBoxes(id, form)
{
    var blacklist = [];
    if(id)
    {
        switch(id)
        {
            case "foo":
            blacklist = ["bar", "baz"];
            break;
            case "bar":
            blacklist = ["foo"];
            break;
            case "baz":
            blacklist = ["foo", "bar"];
            break;
        }   
    }else
    {
        throw new Error("id is needed to hard-wire input blacklist");   
    }
    for(var i=0;i<blacklist.length;i++)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById(blacklist[i]);
        if(element && element.nodeType === 1)
        {
            //check for element
            if(element.tagName === "INPUT" && element.type === "checkbox" && !element.checked)
            {
                element.disabled = "disabled";
            }
        }else if(!element || element.nodeType !== 1)
        {
            throw new Error("input blacklist item does not exist or is not an element");
        }
    }   
}

function enableCheckBoxes(form)
{
    for(var i=0;i<form.elements.length;i++)
    {
        var element = form.elements[i];
        if(element.tagName === "INPUT" && element.type === "checkbox" && !element.checked)
        {
            element.disabled = "";
        }
    }   
}
```

Some quick notes on what I'm doing:

1. I'm using event delegation to minimize the amount of event handlers. The form listens for a click event bubbling up, then calls a function depending on which element was clicked and its `checked` DOM property.
2. I'm traversing the [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLFormElement).[elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements) collection to easily access the checkboxes.
3. I'm setting the `disabled` DOM property to "disabled" on the checkbox if it's not the target checkbox.
4. I'm setting the `disabled` DOM property to "" (an empty string) on the checkbox if no checkboxes are checked.
5. This also works if the user selects the checkbox by tabbing/entering or another method via the `onchange` handler.
6. This code *should* work in IE, though I'm having some serious problems with IE via Wine at work, so I'll have to test later.
7. It uses a "blacklist", which is an array that contains ids to checkboxes you don't want enabled when the corresponding checkbox is clicked.

Let me know if you're looking for anything further.

Comment: you're close Matt, but i would like when user click foo, bar and baz are disable/hide, then when user click bar - only foo is disable. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a set method to that? In other words, is one specific input to be disabled when another is clicked? What's the pattern?

Comment: yes is a set of method, we used this scenario to figure what is the right product base on type of restaurant they are.

Comment: what im looking for is when I have 5 checkboxes Fastfood, Catering, Carryout, Delivery and Bar when user clicked Fastfood ,rest checkboxes are disable, when user checked Catering, rest are disable but when user checked Carryout only Fastfood and Catering are disable. Then when user unchecked, all checkboxes back to enable/show. thanks! –

Comment: I've made a "blacklist" feature that enables you to hard-wire a list of checkbox ids that you want disabled: http://jsfiddle.net/A5TGf/9/. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Matt your a big help! :D

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as "accepted" if you're satisfied (look for the checkmark on the left).

Comment: I made a faux pas with one line of the solution. Please note the revised code above. The pertinent line *was*: `}else if(!element || element.nodeType !== 3)`, but is now: `}else if(!element || element.nodeType !== 1)`.

Comment: Copy ....Thanks a lot its working great! Thanks for helping me out to solve this issues..:)

Answer (score 1):

so i havent completely gotten the logic you are trying to get here.
But if you want to tell if the checkbox was unchecked or checked
you can test it like this

```
 function hideOrShowStuff(box, controlToHide1) {
   if(box.checked) {
     // the hide logic
   } else {
    // the show logic
   }
 }
```

you also need to pass in the box reference
like this

```
 onclick="HideOrShowStuff(this, 1)"
```

hope that helps

Comment: ok, i got on how to check/unchecked or hide/show when one checkbox is checked but what im looking for is when I have 5 checkboxes Fastfood, Catering, Carryout, Delivery and Bar when user clicked Fastfood ,rest checkboxes are disable, when user checked Catering, rest are disable but when user checked Carryout only Fastfood and Catering are disable. Then when user unchecked, all checkboxes back to enable/show. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You **could** use jQuery for this it would (probably) make your life easier. Check out these articles on how to achieve what you want (using jQuery):

[USING JQUERY TO SHOW/HIDE FORM ELEMENTS BASED ON A CHECKBOX SELECTION](http://iamzed.com/2006/12/14/using-jquery-to-show-hide-form-elements-based-on-a-checkbox-selection/)

[Checkboxes + Jquery hide/show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249618/checkboxes-jquery-hide-show)

**NB:** Other frameworks are available. Take your pick according to personal tastes.

Comment: You shouldn't use JQuery if you ever want to know how Javascript actually works, though - maybe the OP wants to learn?

Comment: No he should use Dojo or YUI or Ender.js or ext3 or vanilla js or whatever framework suits this. Just because jquery exists doesn't mean it's the answer.

Comment: This is far too simple for jQuery, I think. Setting DOM properties isn't very difficult.

Comment: Easy... I didn't say it was the only answer, I just said it would make it easier than the code he had. I'll amend the answer to make that more clear. Easier as in shorter, and easier to manage, plus being more likely to be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Wow, marked down for mentioning jQuery. I'll wash my mouth out with soap. While jQuery isn't the only framework on the block, and subjectively it could be argued it's not the best, if you're building web apps then it can be a good choice for many. Yes jQuery is only JS in a wrapper, and yes sometimes plain ole JS is easy enough for the job, but if you've got a whole web app to build then using a framework from the off, for the big and little things alike makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using a framework or toolkit (like jQuery) will make life easier, but it's probably best to learn how the manipulate the DOM with javascript before moving on to a toolkit. Like learning to add before using a calculator.

The best way to deal with this is to look at the state of your checkboxes. if(document.myform.box2.checked == true), then make decisions based on the state of your checkboxes. The function you have above simply modifies the checkboxes without knowing anything about their state. It would be better to just pass (this) to the function, and then walk the DOM. "this" would be the checkbox when it comes into the function as a parameter. So your function would say "okay, I've got checkbox "1" passed to me, now what is the state of my other checkboxes?".

Comment: i got on how to hide/show but im looking for different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <script>
            function uncheck0(){
                for(var ii=1; ii<=3; ii++){
                    if(document.getElementById("q6_"+ii).checked==true){
                       document.getElementById("q6_"+ii).checked=false;
                    }
                }
            }
            function uncheck(id, from, to){
                for(var ii=from; ii<=to; ii++){
                    if(document.getElementById(id+ii).checked==true){
                       document.getElementById(id+ii).checked=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shareefhiasat/EHz74/4/)

```
function changeCheckBox() {
     try {

         var max = document.mainForm.serNo.length;
         var count = 0;

         for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
             if (document.mainForm.serNo[i].checked == true) {
                 count++;
                 serNoChecked = i;
             }
         }
         if (count == 1) {
             for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                 if (document.mainForm.serNo[i].checked == false) {
                     document.mainForm.serNo[i].disabled = true;
                 }
             }
         } else if (count == 0) {
             for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                 document.mainForm.serNo[i].disabled = false;
             }
         }

         if (null == max) return false;
         if (count == 0) {
             return true;
         } else if (count > 0) {
             return false;
         }

     } catch (e) {
         alert(e.message);
     }
 }



<form  name="mainForm" method="GET" action="Controller">
<TD STYLE="width:10px">
    <input type="checkbox" id="serNo" name="serNo" value="" onclick="changeCheckBox()" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="serNo" name="serNo" value="" onclick="changeCheckBox()" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="serNo" name="serNo" value="" onclick="changeCheckBox()" />
</TD>
</form>
```